# Multiple unique morphMany relations Laravel 4

Tags: polymorphism, laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations, eloquent

In Laravel 4 Eloquent is it possible to have a model that has two or more unique morphMany() relations to another model? (polymorphic)

e.g.

```
class Application extends Eloquent {

    public function resume()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Upload', 'uploadable');
    }    

    public function coverLetter()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Upload', 'uploadable');
    }  

...
```

The code above does not work as when i try to retrieve either of the relations sometime get an upload model that i dont want e.g.

```
$application->resume->file_name // this sometimes echos a coverLetter
```

Comment: For a polymorphic relationship you need at least another model relates to Uploads, else it would be better to use a one to many relationship.

Comment: Yes... I'm aware of that. I do have other models relating to uploads.

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you end up resolving? It seems the only solution would be to create 2 pivot tables application_resume and application_cover_letter.

Comment: There is a good solution to this same problem posted here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835996/laravel-4-multiple-polymorphic-relations-from-one-model

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're misunderstanding why polymorphic relations should be used.

This would be your fix:

```
class Application extends Eloquent {

public function resume()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Resume');
}    

public function coverLetter()
{
    return $this->hasMany('CoverLetter');
}  

// ...
```

The reason that you can't have both as polymorphic is because you simply can't tell which one you should be getting. Your 'uploadable' could be a coverletter or a resume, but you can't tell if they're both being described as uploadable. You have to differentiate them in the models. Laravel isn't that magical!