# Laravel 4, Multiple Polymorphic Relations from one Model

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I'm trying to set up polymorphic relationships in Laravel 4 so that I can have one Image class which handles everything related to uploads, unlinks and so on, then have it used by multiple different Models. That's fine, until I get to trying to create multiple links from the same Model.

For example, I currently have something like this:

Models/Image.php

```
class Image extends Eloquent {
    public function of() { return $this->morphTo(); }
}
```

Models/Person.php

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
    public function mugshot() { return $this->morphOne('Image', 'of'); }
    public function photos() { return $this->morphMany('Image', 'of'); }
}
```

Models/Place.php

```
class Place extends Eloquent {
    public function photos() { return $this->morphMany('Image', 'of'); }
}
```

Here, a Person can upload one `mugshot` and many `photos`, while a Place can have many `photos`. The problem is that when I create a `mugshot` on a Person, it saves this into the `images` table in the database:

```
id: 1
of_id: 1
of_type: Person
```

It doesn't store the fact that it's a `mugshot` and not a `photo`, so when I go to retrieve it, `$person->mugshot` may sometimes return one of `$person->photos` and vice versa.

Is there either (a) a better way to do this than creating 2 links on the same Model, or (b) a way to actually make this way work?

Comment: Can I ask how your database table relations look like? I think I have a similar case, but not sure how to setup the relations to use morphOne()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No built-in way right now. Maybe in Laravel 4.1 that's supposed to bring a complete rewrite of polymorphic relations.

Add a `type` property to `Image`, then define `where` conditions on the relations:

```
public function mugshot() { 
    return $this->morphOne('Image', 'of')->where('type', 'mugshot'); 
}

public function photos() { 
    return $this->morphMany('Image', 'of')->where('type', 'photo'); 
}
```

Don't forget to set `type` on `Image`s you create.
Or, like I did bellow, hide that logic inside the model.

Here's my code (I'm using PHP 5.4 with short array notation):

Image:

```
namespace SP\Models;

class Image extends BaseModel {

    const MUGSHOT = 'mugshot';
    const PHOTO = 'photo';

    protected $hidden = ['type'];

    public function of()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Person:

```
namespace SP\Models;

use SP\Models\Image;

class Person extends BaseModel {

    public function mugshot() { 
        return $this->morphOne('SP\Models\Image', 'of')
                            ->where('type', Image::MUGSHOT); 
    }

    public function photos() { 
        return $this->morphMany('SP\Models\Image', 'of')
                            ->where('type', Image::PHOTO); 
    }

    public function saveMugshot($image)
    {
        $image->type = Image::MUGSHOT;
        $image->save();
        $this->mugshot()->save($image);
    }

    public function savePhotos($images)
    {
        if(!is_array($images))
        {
            $images = [$images];
        }

        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            $image->type = Image::PHOTO;
            $image->save();
            $this->photos()->save($image);
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in a controller/service:

```
$person->savePhotos([$image1, $image2]);
```

Comment: That looks pretty pretty, as code goes :) I'll be working on the project later on today, so I'll let you know how things go - if it all goes smoothly (and I think it will, the idea looks sound), I'll accept and bounty you :) Cheers

Comment: Happy days, it's all good :) Thanks a lot for your time, it's much appreciated

Comment: As a note, from my test, it appears that ->where is no longer required if you are using laravel's auto naming for the columns for type. Which in the this case would be `of_type`. At least to my understanding.